# Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE error while using MediaProjectionManager

Tags: android

I am trying to use Media projection API to enable screen capturing ability in my app. I am not able to call getsystemservice in Android Studio. I am getting an error on  Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE :Must be one of the context.power_service,context.window_service error. Any suggestions to get it working?? or why am I getting this error??

Answer (score 0):

It is a wrong warning and it's okay to ignore. This was fixed in a later update, as I no longer get that warning (I used to).

Either:

- Update Android Studio
- Update your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion` in your `build.gradle` file (Make sure you update in the SDK Manager also.)